# CentOS 7 hang on boot

Tags: centos, boot

I have CentOS 7 installed.
Today I did several things:

- Installed OpenFOAM

  - ran `yum update`
  - Installed Docker
  - Installed and tested OpenFOAM
- Tried installing NVidia driver

  - Failed as was in XWindows
  - tried stopping XWindows with `gdm stop`, failed
  - tried `init 3`, offered blinking cursor on screen, forced to reboot

Now the machine hangs on boot. The 'recovery' item in GRUB will boot, however locks up at `[Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes]`. A Ctrl+F2 gives the opportunity to log in. The previous kernel will boot to a dated GUI, the current kernel will not.

The previous kernel is only partially aware of the OpenFOAM installation, but is obviously missing some key parts. `yum update` in it says there's nothing to do.

What has gone wrong here and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You should post details on where the machine hangs on boot for anyone to be able to help You with that.

Comment: The OP did say where it hangs: " . . . at [Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes”] . . ."

Comment: I am having a similar problem - in that my CentOS 7 boot hangs at the same command, regardless of which kernel version I use. It even hangs in the rescue mode. Since my installation is a file server, there should be nothing complicated installed, such as in the OP. I've found similar hangs in various distros (online search). They mostly seem to be having issues with video drivers. What I've found that may be useful are these two pages: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/ and https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-an-lvm-volume-partition-command/

Comment: This was a little while ago, but something to check is where the video output is going. I did have one issue that in fact wasn't an issue because for whatever reason, at that point in bootup, the graphics output was being redirected to the VGA/PCIe etc. and in fact wasn't hanging at all.